# Create dynamic radiobuttonlist from object properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic, properties, radiobuttonlist

I have a list of objects of multiple choice questions. I need to create a RadioButtonList with the object properties: Choice_A, Choice_B,... Choice_D.

```
var qs = (from questions in dc.Survey_Questions
                  where questions.Survey_ID == surveyid                     
                  select new SQuestions
                  {
                      QuestionID = questions.Question_ID,
                      SurveyID = questions.Survey_ID,                         
                      Description = questions.Description,
                      Choice_A = questions.Choice_A,
                      Choice_B = questions.Choice_B,
                      Choice_C = questions.Choice_C,
                      Choice_D = questions.Choice_D,
                    }).ToList();
DataList dtQuestion.DataSource = qs;
```

HTML Structure:

```
<asp:DataList ID="dtQuestion" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Vertical" >`
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# Eval("Description") %> `          
    <ItemTemplate> 
    <RadioButtonList></RadiobuttonList>
    </ItemTemplate>

    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, try modelling SQuestion to match the following:

```
public class SQuestion
{
    int QuestionId = 0; //int? change to whatever
    int SurveyId = 0; //same as above
    string Description = string.Empty;
    List<string> Choices = new List<string>(); //notice this is a list
}
```

So now you can bind the choices to a drop down list.
I would recommend using the onDataBinding method or onDataBound (its one of them, off the top of my head I'm not sure) and you can then bind the inner choice drop down list with the current question.Choices.  That should work.

Hope this helps point you in the right direction.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I think I have a good lead now but I'm getting the error: Unhandled binding type: ListBinding <br>select new SQuestions
                  {
                      QuestionID = questions.Question_ID,
                      Description = questions.Description,Choices = {questions.Choice_A,  questions.Choice_B,  questions.Choice_C}